# Tests are not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I'm using RSpec for tests and I don't know how to get this to green.

In this case, I have a model called "PartType" that holds an attribute called "quotation".

The value for quotation comes from a form, so it will be a string.

To demonstrate you can go to console and type:

```
(1..1000).includes?("50") # false
```

but..

```
(1..1000).includes?(50) # true
```

And this value can have decimals. So I needed to do a "type_cast".

I have this on my `PartType`model:

```
before_validation :fix_quotation, :if => :quotation_changed?

protected
  def fix_quotation
    self[:quotation] = quotation_before_type_cast.tr(' $, ' , '.' )
  end
```

This are working as expected BUT when go to tests, it fails.

Here is my `part_type_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PartType do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :title => "Silver", :quotation => 100 }
  end

  it "should create a instance given a valid attributes" do
    PartType.create!(@attr)
  end

  it "should accept null value for quotation" do
    PartType.new(@attr.merge(:quotation => nil)).should be_valid
  end

  it "should accept 0 value for quotation" do
    PartType.new(@attr.merge(:quotation => 0)).should be_valid
  end

end
```

And finally the failing tests:

```
Failures:
```

1) PartType should create a instance given a valid attributes
     Failure/Error: PartType.create!(@attr)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `tr' for 100:Fixnum
     # ./app/models/part_type.rb:7:in`fix_quotation'
     # ./spec/models/part_type_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in '

2) PartType should accept 0 value for quotation
     Failure/Error: PartType.new(@attr.merge(:quotation => 0)).should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `tr' for 0:Fixnum
     # ./app/models/part_type.rb:7:in`fix_quotation'
     # ./spec/models/part_type_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in '

Finished in 0.06089 seconds
3 examples, 2 failures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `include?` snippets are wrong, I got false in the first, true in the second.
2. `before_validation` is executed and `quotation_before_type_cast` is expected to be a `String` but it is a `Fixnum`. Change `100` to `'100'` and `0` to `'0'`.

Comment: Edited the snippets, thanks for that. And should I always have to refer a value as a string? even I want it to be a integer value?

Comment: Yes, because you are expecting them to be a string in your `before_validation` method.